# electron-react-boilerplate + react-i18next not working when bundled

Tags: reactjs, electron, react-i18next

I used [electron-react-boilerplate](https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate) to set up my app.

Now I wanted to add i18n. I used [react-i18next](https://react.i18next.com/). This is my config:

`src/services/i18n.tsx`

```
import i18next from 'i18next';
import { LocaleEn, LocalePl } from 'locales';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';

const resources = {
  en: {
    translation: LocaleEn,
  },
  pl: {
    translation: LocalePl,
  },
};

i18next.use(initReactI18next).init({
  resources,
  lng: 'en',
  interpolation: {
    escapeValue: false,
  },
  supportedLngs: ['en', 'pl'],
});

export default i18next;
```

(and I import it in my `index.tsx` file)

The `LocaleEn` and `LocalePl` are imported - these are just objects that contain my translations (defined in `src/locales/{en,pl}.tsx`)

Now, everything works perfectly, I'm able to get the translations with `useTranslation()`. The problem starts when I want to package my app. I run `npm run package` and execute the resulting binary. However, the translations are not here. I mean, for example I have something like

```json
{
  [...]
  mainMenu: {
    title: "Foo",
  },
  [...]
}
```

And I use it like:

```
const { t } = useTranslation();
return <div>t('mainMenu.title')</div>
```

But instead of `Foo` I get `mainMenu.title`. And this only happens when I package/bundle the application like I mentioned above. During the development (when running `npm start`) everything works fine.

Is there something I have to do to make it work? Maybe electron configuration?

P.S I'm not so much opposed to using JSONs instead of defining my translations in javascript, however I prefer this for now, as the app is not that big.